# Trigger a segue to another view controller with qr code scanner (Xcode/Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, qr-code

as of now, my qr code scanner is only able to scan to a web url instead, how can I trigger a segue push from my qrscannercontroller to another uiviewcontroller?
My friend has already done his using android studio with a qr code static text.

This is my qrscannercontroller.swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class QRScannerController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var messageLabel:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var topbar: UIView!

    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?

    let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video as the media type parameter.
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {
            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

            // Initialize the captureSession object.
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

            // Set the input device on the capture session.
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

            // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

            // Start video capture.
            captureSession?.startRunning()

            // Move the message label and top bar to the front
            view.bringSubview(toFront: messageLabel)
            view.bringSubview(toFront: topbar)

            // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

            if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
                view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
                view.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
            }

        } catch {
            // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate Methods

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
            messageLabel.text = "No QR/barcode is detected"
            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                let url = URL(string: metadataObj.stringValue)!
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is my uiviewcontroller

```
import UIKit    
class Quiz1Controller: UIViewController {    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: change code with url opening to segue code

Comment: is there any example/solution u can show me? I'm quite new to Xcode sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

      //Here you can implement the code to push viewController

        }
    }
```

You can either use `performSegue(withIdentifier: yourId, sender: nil)` after connecting segue from the storyBoard or you can use

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourNextViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check, weather the `url` can be open.  If you scanned the `url` it will open in browser. If it is not `url` then you can handle the action based on your logic.

> Don't forcefully unwrap the `URL` values. It returns `optional value`. So use `if let` to make sure the values are not `nil`

```
if let url = URL(string: metadataObj.stringValue) {
       if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
             } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
             }
        } else {
            //Logic to choose view controller identifier
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "quiz1VC segue id", sender: self)
        }
 }
```

**Update:**

**Issue :** "QRCode scanning completion block executed multiple times"

**Solution :**

```
if let _ = metadataObj.stringValue { 
   captureSession?.stopRunning() // Stop session before perform segue.
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("abc", sender: self) 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Subramanian, actually i do not want the url anymore, i just want my qr code scanner to link to 10 uiviewcontroller instead based on 10 qr codes generated

Comment: Are you scanning url or some text?

Comment: @Kinja If you are scanning some text then use your view controller segue id as same as your scanned text. And add only perform `performSegue(withIdentifier: "scanned id", sender: self)`. If you are matching one view controller for multiple scanned text then use `switch case` to pick the `segue id `

Comment: Let's say i got 2 Quiz UIView, Quiz 1 & 2. What i need is the QR Scanner View to go to Quiz 1 uiview when  the scanner detected "abc" as result. while result ="efg" go to Quiz2 uiview

Comment: it's ok bro, i managed to solve it already. However, now it opens my uiviewcontroller twice when i scan the qr code. how can i only make it open once? This is my codes: http://imgur.com/PuWou7i

Comment: befor `performSegue(withIdentifier: "abc", sender: self)` line of code stop your session `captureSession?.stopRunning() `

Comment: `if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            captureSession?.stopRunning()  
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("abc", sender: self)
        }`

Comment: NICE! Thank you so much bro, really appreciate it, you're a genius!